# Perl - How to determine if user visits site through one of the search engines

Tags: perl

Is there any way to find out if user visits site through any one of the search engines (Google/Yahoo/Bing etc.. ) using Perl? 
In my project I've to find out if user visits the site through one of the search engines.

CGI referer can be used to find out what user was viewing prior but after getting the URL, matching has to be done for all search engines to find out if it has come through search engines (Google/Yahoo/Bing etc.. ) which would not be feasible

my $cgi = new CGI;
print $cgi->referer();

Can someone shed light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty much what you have to do:  Get the referer, then check it against a list of search engines.  There's no way to determine whether an arbitrary URL belongs to a search engine other than by examining the text of the URL.